# 2 blocks are still reachable in loss record cs50 dictionary.c

Tags: c, cs50

// Implements a dictionary's functionality

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

#define HASHTABLE_SIZE 10000

// Defines struct for a node
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

node *hashtable[HASHTABLE_SIZE];

// Hashes the word (hash function posted on reddit by delipity)
// The word you want to hash is contained within new node, arrow, word.
// Hashing that will give you the index. Then you insert word into linked list.
int hash_index(char *hash_this)
{
    unsigned int hash = 0;
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(hash_this); i < n; i++)
    {
        hash = (hash << 2) ^ hash_this[i];
    }
    return hash % HASHTABLE_SIZE;
}

// Initializes counter for words in dictionary
int word_count = 0;

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // Opens dictionary
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Scans dictionary word by word (populating hash table with nodes containing words found in dictionary)
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        // Mallocs a node for each new word (i.e., creates node pointers)
        node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
        // Checks if malloc succeeded, returns false if not
        if (new_node == NULL)
        {
            unload();
            return false;
        }
        // Copies word into node if malloc succeeds
        strcpy(new_node->word, word);

        // Initializes & calculates index of word for insertion into hashtable
        int h = hash_index(new_node->word);

        // Initializes head to point to hashtable index/bucket
        node *head = hashtable[h];

        // Inserts new nodes at beginning of lists
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            hashtable[h] = new_node;
            word_count++;
        }
        else
        {
            new_node->next = hashtable[h];
            hashtable[h] = new_node;
            word_count++;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return true;
}

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // Creates copy of word on which hash function can be performed
    int n = strlen(word);
    char word_copy[LENGTH + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        word_copy[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    }
    // Adds null terminator to end string
    word_copy[n] = '\0';
    // Initializes index for hashed word
    int h = hash_index(word_copy);
    // Sets cursor to point to same address as hashtable index/bucket
    node *cursor = hashtable[h];
    // Sets cursor to point to same location as head

    // If the word exists, you should be able to find in dictionary data structure.
    // Check for word by asking, which bucket would word be in? hashtable[hash(word)]
    // While cursor does not point to NULL, search dictionary for word.
    while (cursor != NULL)
    {
        // If strcasecmp returns true, then word has been found
        if (strcasecmp(cursor->word, word_copy) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        // Else word has not yet been found, advance cursor
        else
        {
            cursor = cursor->next;
        }
    }
    // Cursor has reached end of list and word has not been found in dictionary so it must be misspelled
    return false;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return word_count;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    node *head = NULL;
    node *cursor = head;
    // freeing linked lists
    while (cursor != NULL)
    {
        node *temp = cursor;
        cursor = cursor->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    return true;
}
```

```
running valgrind --show-leak-kinds=all --xml=yes --xml-file=/tmp/tmpnje9pfrb -- ./speller substring/dict substring/text...
checking for output "MISSPELLED WORDS\\n\\nca\\ncats\\ncaterpill\\ncaterpillars\\n\\nWORDS MISSPELLED: 4\\nWORDS IN DICTIONARY: 2\\nWORDS IN TEXT: 6\\n"...
checking that program exited with status 0...
checking for valgrind errors...
112 bytes in 2 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1: (file: dictionary.c, line: 54)
```

Alright, the challenge now before you is to implement, in order, load, hash, size, check, and unload as efficiently as possible using a hash table in such a way that TIME IN load, TIME IN check, TIME IN size, and TIME IN unload are all minimized. To be sure, it’s not obvious what it even means to be minimized, inasmuch as these benchmarks will certainly vary as you feed speller different values for dictionary and for text. But therein lies the challenge, if not the fun, of this problem. This problem is your chance to design. Although we invite you to minimize space, your ultimate enemy is time. But before you dive in, some specifications from us.

You may not alter speller.c or Makefile.
You may alter dictionary.c (and, in fact, must in order to complete the implementations of load, hash, size, check, and unload), but you may not alter the declarations (i.e., prototypes) of load, hash, size, check, or unload. You may, though, add new functions and (local or global) variables to dictionary.c.
You may change the value of N in dictionary.c, so that your hash table can have more buckets.
You may alter dictionary.h, but you may not alter the declarations of load, hash, size, check, or unload.
Your implementation of check must be case-insensitive. In other words, if foo is in dictionary, then check should return true given any capitalization thereof; none of foo, foO, fOo, fOO, fOO, Foo, FoO, FOo, and FOO should be considered misspelled.
Capitalization aside, your implementation of check should only return true for words actually in dictionary. Beware hard-coding common words (e.g., the), lest we pass your implementation a dictionary without those same words. Moreover, the only possessives allowed are those actually in dictionary. In other words, even if foo is in dictionary, check should return false given foo's if foo's is not also in dictionary.
You may assume that any dictionary passed to your program will be structured exactly like ours, alphabetically sorted from top to bottom with one word per line, each of which ends with \n. You may also assume that dictionary will contain at least one word, that no word will be longer than LENGTH (a constant defined in dictionary.h) characters, that no word will appear more than once, that each word will contain only lowercase alphabetical characters and possibly apostrophes, and that no word will start with an apostrophe.
You may assume that check will only be passed words that contain (uppercase or lowercase) alphabetical characters and possibly apostrophes.
Your spell checker may only take text and, optionally, dictionary as input. Although you might be inclined (particularly if among those more comfortable) to “pre-process” our default dictionary in order to derive an “ideal hash function” for it, you may not save the output of any such pre-processing to disk in order to load it back into memory on subsequent runs of your spell checker in order to gain an advantage.
Your spell checker must not leak any memory. Be sure to check for leaks with valgrind.
The hash function you write should ultimately be your own, not one you search for online. There are many ways to implement a hash function beyond using the first character (or characters) of a word. Consider a hash function that uses a sum of ASCII values or the length of a word. A good hash function tends to reduce “collisions” and has a fairly even distribution across hash table “buckets”.

Comment: Please don't tag multiple languages, only the one your code is actually written in. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to copy-paste (as text) the full and complete Valgrind output, and show us a proper [mre].

Comment: As a hint about your problem, what is the `unload` function *really* doing? Please try to explain it in great detail to a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: Please don't just dump description of CS50 task. Even more, don't just dump a wall of text that is really hard to read. A task description is very different from a problem description. Also a task and a problem are different things. Tell us what problem you have with your code. The task description surely will not include any memory leaks or other errors in your code.